# “Projects I'm proud of” + “most”

Tags: grammar

I have a caption “Projects I'm proud of” in my presentation. I'd like to accent that I'm proud of them much more, than others. Would it be grammatically correct to add “most”: “Projects I'm proud of most”? Does it sound natural? Should I use a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural would be:

> Projects I am most proud of

('Projects of which I am the most proud' might sound too formal for this context).

Not a rule, but many would advise you to use "I am", not the contraction "I'm", in a title.

I have no idea why you are asking about commas. There is no place for one in this title.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In some languages there should be a comma after “Projects”, so I was not sure is it optional or redundant in English.